# Joomla display a streaming video

Tags: video, joomla, video-streaming

i need to read a streaming video from a joomla 2.5 website.
Any clue to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By "read" I assume you mean "watch".

Before asking questions likes this, you should really check the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org), where you will find loads of extensions regarding videos. Sorry I can't give a more specific answer, however you might need to provide more detail in your question.

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking to read a video from a ip webcam directly in my website, i didn't find any components that can fit my requirement...I will use JW Player and a home made component!